# Python Problem importing function from module

Tags: python

So i'm using a RPI4 to program some code in python. As it was growing i decided to separate this in multiple scripts/modules according to functions, variables and classes.

After doing all that i got an error when calling the function after import. I tried adding **init**.py, but it shouldn'0t be necesary as the modules are in the same folder.

I tried with some tests scripts/modules and got the same error:

Folder: test

--test
----test1.py
----test2.py

test2.py:

```
def print_test():
    print("test")
```

for test1.py i have 2 cases:

case1, test1.py:

```
import test2
test2.print_test()
```

error: AttributeError: module 'test2' has no attribute 'print_test'

case2, test1.py:

```
from test2 import *
print_test()
```

error: NameError: name 'print_test' is not defined

i've lost a lot of time on this and after extensive searching, nothing seems to work

Comment: What's the output of `print(test2.__file__)` in `test1.py` after `import test2`? Is it what you expect?

Comment: yes, it is "/home/pi/test/test2.py"

Comment: And what's the output of `print(dir(test2))`?

Comment: From what you have described, you should not get these errors. I can only imagine that you forgot to save the file or have edited the wrong file or something like that.

Comment: i feel so stupid, i was assuming that as i was pressing the upload button all files saved automatically. But only the main file was saved. LOL i'll have to remember to press  ctrl+s